# Query two tables for a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have two models:

```
class Student(models.Model):

    student_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    student_lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    student_firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    student_courseid = models.ForeignKey(Course)

class Course(models.Model):
    course_location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course_begin = models.DateField(blank=True)
    course_end = models.DateField(blank=True)
```

I have a form where I display the information for each student. The student is selected via the url.

```
urlpatterns = [
        # ex: /00116777/detail/
    url(r'^(?P<studentid>[0-9]+)/detail/$', StudentDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

]
```

In this form I would like to add the course_location but I cannot figure out how to query both so that I can use it in the Template as

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                <p class="student-detail-data">{{ course.course_location }}</p>
</div>
```

This is my view so far:

```
class StudentDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Student
    template_name = "student/detail.html"
    slug_field = 'student_id'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'studentid'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StudentDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data = self.kwargs['studentid']
        context['object'] = Student.objects.filter(student_id=data)
        return context
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in in template by foreign key `{{ student.student_courseid.course_location }}`

And not nessery to create `student_id`, Django automaticly add `pk`.
I don't know, what kind of logic you want, but I think for courses and students, you need to create `models.ManyToManyField`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked (and was even easier than expected). Short follow up question regarding the ID: I will import data from another system where each student already has a given ID which I would like to adapt as primary_key. In that context, do I still not need to define a specific id field?

Comment: I'm not clearly understand what system you mean. You want import model from some module or what? About `pk` just saying, django can create it automaticly, and your objects im db always have `pk`

Answer (score 0):

On click of a particular student, it must show the information(course details also)

so I guess, this will work.

```
{{student.student_courseid.course_loation}} in your html page.
```

Hope this should work, because by default.